# Use Implicit conversion before Templating

Tags: c++, template-specialization, overload-resolution

I'm trying to use a combination of template specialization and implicit conversion to sort templated types in to 3 categories:

1. types that can be implicitly converted to a string
2. types that can be implicitly converted to a double
3. types that cannot be implicitly converted to a string nor double

In this attempt of mine, however, all types that could have been converted into either a double or a string end up in the default case of type T.

```
template<>
void Foo(std::string s)
{
    //can be converted to a string
}

template<>
void Foo(double d)
{
    //can be converted to a double
}

template<typename T>
void Foo(T t)
{
    //cannot be converted to a string or a double 
}

struct Other {};

int main()
{
    Foo("bar");// creates Foo(const char*) instead of converting to string
    Foo(1);// creates Foo(int) instead of converting to double
    Other o
    Foo(o);// creates Foo(Other)
}
```

On the other hand, implicit conversion works if the templating is removed, but at the cost of being able to handle the "neither" types.

```
void Foo(std::string s)
{
    //can be converted to a string
}

void Foo(double d)
{
    //can be converted to a double
}

struct Other {};

int main()
{
    Foo("bar");// const char* -> std::string
    Foo(1);// int -> double
    Other o
    Foo(o);// No overload available for this type
}
```

Is there a way to prioritize implicit conversion to existing specialized templates before creating a new templated function? Or perhaps is there an entirely different way I should be approaching this problem?

Comment: You could use SFINAE: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae.

Answer (score 5):

Don't specialize... Honestly, if there's a problem X with a solution Y, then specializing function templates is almost invariably Z. For a specialization to be called, the deduced template arguments must be *exactly* the ones we are specializing over. Moreover, whether a specialization exists or not **isn't even considered in overload resolution**! The overload is resolved from the primary template *declaration* alone.

For your problem you need to overload, so that the two custom cases are *always* considered in overload resolution. Then you just have to make sure the general catch-call function is simply discarded when needed. SFINAE, along with some standard type traits will accomplish exactly that.

```
#include <type_traits>

// Overloads. Not templates!

void Foo(std::string s)
{
    //can be converted to a string
}


void Foo(double d)
{
    //can be converted to a double
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string> || std::is_convertible_v<T, double>)>
Foo(T t)
{
    //cannot be converted to a string or a double 
}
```

See how the condition is exactly what you want to check? The type traits verify if a conversion is possible, in which case `std::enable_if_t` is an ill-formed type (doesn't exist). So the overload is simply discarded (because **S**ubstitution **F**ailure **I**s **N**ot **A**n **E**rror). The other two overloads are still there, so one of them gets chosen.

If neither conversion is possible, then the template overload is not discarded, and `std::enable_if_t` - the return type of the function - is void (`void` is what `enable_if_t` resolves to by default).

---

If you have access to newer compilers that support the latest C++ standard, you can even write it in a way that is more user-friendly than classic SFINAE

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
    requires !(std::convertible_to<T, std::string> || std::convertible_to<T, double>)
void Foo(T t)
{
    //cannot be converted to a string or a double 
}
```

The constraint can now occupy it's own place in the declaration, leaving the return type out of the magic.

Comment: Depending on the use-case, Id argue that constexpr if + type traits is a more straightforward solution than sfinae, even with the new c++20 way of doing it. But that is personal taste, still a good and valid answer +1

Comment: @Wutz - Like all things in life, it depends. If this is a header that is used by many TU's and the branch bodies deal in concrete types, then I consider the application of `if constexpr` an anti-pattern. Concrete overloads can be compiled separately along with their dependencies. This keeps headers neat and small. An `if constexpr` will require the whole party be brought in every time. I prefer the `if consexpr` branches to still be generic. It's a great tool to dispense with artficial tag dispatch.